# Is it possible to boot one OS in each of the three ssd of Samsung Odyssey 2 laptop?

Tags: ssd, bios, multi-boot

I want to buy the Odyssey 2 gaming laptop.However, I will need to use one OS in each of its ssd,and the laptop has three slots to install the ssds. One of them is a SATA 3,the M.2(that will came with installed Windows 10, and Samsung named it as replaceable) and the other is NVME(that Samsung named it as scalable).So,is it possible?

I asked Samsung about this specific configuration. Then,they told me that the system might have some incompatibilities and that was the point where they don't recommend me. However, I've never tried it before to know how it really works.

Ps: I don't want to install two OS in just one hardware,and my configuration will be: Windows 10,and two others Linux distros.

Comment: It depends if system will boot from each of the drives. Some that have drives that do not boot but otherwise work, install either just the boot loader or boot loader & /boot folder into the bootable drive. Ubuntu only wants to install its boot loader to whatever drive is first in boot order. Windows wants to install boot files into drive seen as default in UEFI/BIOS. All system should be in some boot mode. If you can turn a drive off in UEFI settings then that may be best option when installing.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your tips! I've just updated my question and , regards of some doubts that I have about when a system boots,I'll ask new questions. After reading your awnser and some researches, I'm faced with at least two others doubts.

Comment: My older desktops only have one M.2 port. Older one is SATA only, newer can be SATA or NVMe but then it may remove a SATA port from use. Desktop has lots of ports so not an issue. May want to see if you can download manual and read all the fine print. Just about every vendor says they do not support Linux. But most work, although some need boot parameters or have some minor issue which may be major to you. have not seen many questions on Samsung - https://askubuntu.com/questions/760102/ubuntu-16-04-error-installing-grub/762267#762267 Issues often common by brand. Bigger diff if AMD or Intel.

Comment: @oldfred I talked with Samsung's employee and he said me that if I set dual boot on Odyssey laptop I can damage the computer(BIOS) letting it unbootable (brick).You can check more about this topic: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12584/14137
https://superuser.com/q/1512837/1120712.

Comment: The manual has all the standard we are not responsible legalese that all vendors use. Samsung is behind other vendors is is at least thinking about supporting UEFI updates from within Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/vendors/